# How does swagger shield the default interface?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

As shown in the following figure, the swagger document will always generate a Swagger interface by default, carefully study the configuration file, and do not see the option to block this interface.

[image]

This interface is useless here. How can I block this default interface?